# How two overcome the Rust's restriction of 1 lib + n bins per crate when one of the bins has its own dependencies?

Tags: rust, file-structure

I have a Rust project (it's a Minesweeper game implementation).

The whole functionality of the game itself is written as a library, so that it could be 1) shared as a crate on crates.io and 2) used with different frontends.

At the moment I have 2 frontends: the first one is `debug_main`, which is just the most basic textual input/output for the game; the other one is `main` which is a TUI written in [ratatui](https://ratatui.rs/).

[image]

The current issue is that I don't like the files structure. The biggest problem is that now everything inside the `bin` folder is considered a separate executable. So I can run `cargo run --bin main` and `--bin debug_main` as well as `--bin app` and `--bin game_ui`, which is not what I want, as there are only 2 executables: `main` and `debug_main`, and all the other files (`app`, `event`, `game_ui`, `menu_ui`, `tui` and `update`) are the dependencies of `main`.

This file structure [comes from ratatui](https://ratatui.rs/tutorials/counter-app/multiple-files/): since it's a framework, not just a library, it dictates the file/project structure to stick to (obviously, I understand that I can deviate from it, but not an expert enough to think that "I know better").

So, what they're dictating, is effectively splitting your app into an executable (`main`) and the lib (all the other files). But for me (*as i understand it*) there's a problem that I already have a lib. And, as far as I know, it's impossible to have more than one lib per crate.

What do I do in my case? How can I abstract at least all the files in the `bin` folder (except the two executables `main` and `debug_main`), so that they don't become executables as well? How do I structure my project when it's devided into 1 lib and many binaries, but at the same time binaries themselves may require underlying libs? **In general**, how do I put things in order in my project? What are the best recoomendations?

For reference, here's the `Cargo.toml` file's contents (nothing special about it):

```
[package]
name = "miners"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.4.18", features = ["derive"] }
color-eyre = "0.6.2"
crossterm = "0.27.0"
rand = "0.8.5"
ratatui = "0.25.0"
```

Here's what the `mod` declarations look like in `main.rs`:

```rust
mod app;
mod event;
mod game_ui;
mod menu_ui;
mod tui;
mod update;
```

and in `debug_main`

```rust
use miners::{field::Field, Minesweeper, MinesweeperAction, MinesweeperStatus};
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html: "*If a binary ... consists of multiple source files, place a `main.rs` file along with the extra modules within a subdirectory of the `src/bin` ... directory. The name of the executable will be the directory name.*"

Comment: @eggyal indeed, that works. Missed that part. Thanks! Why not as an answer though?

Comment: I hesitated to post as an answer because your question raises other points and asks more general questions such file reorganisation alone does not solve; a complete answer would be more than I could comfortably write on my phone.  But, if you are happy with that as an answer, by all means feel free to post as an answer to your own question. :)

Comment: Someone please post it as an answer.  It helps visibility and I wasn't able to find a similar enough question to the problem.

Comment: Well that [answer was already posted on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76238267/442760) not sure if dupe or just rel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1. Create a Cargo Workspace separating the different applications from each others and have multiple libs you want to share individually; this allows you to have separate dependencies for each (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html)
2. Make use of a multi-file-executable (https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html)

```
    ├── src/
    │   ├── lib.rs
    │   ├── some_module.rs
    │   └── bin/
    │       ├── debug/
    │       │   ├── main.rs
    │       │   └── some_module.rs
    │       └── tui/
    │           ├── main.rs
    │           └── some_module.rs
```

Each folder or `module` under `bin`-directory will be a separate executable being build. The name of the executable will be the directory name.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I would benefit from using workspaces only if I wanted to share a "bin's lib" as a create? If there's the only crate I'd like to share (the main lib one), then there's no need in my particular case to use workspaces?

Comment: You can have different dependencies for each bin crate when using workspaces. This would prevent you from using a tui lib in debug bin, e.g.

Comment: Ok, that's nice. Thanks for the tip.